# actionPerformed and method equals not working with controller

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

This code is supposed to create a new window from my main window when I press miALote... but it doesn't, I don't know what I'm doing wrong... If I delete the if from the controller, it works, but that's not supposed to happen so... This is the main controller code:

```
package Controller.GUI;

import GUI.AltaLote;
import GUI.MenuPrincipal;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Controller implements ActionListener{

MenuPrincipal ventanaControlada;

public Controller(MenuPrincipal win){
    this.ventanaControlada=win;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if (e.getSource().equals(ventanaControlada.miALote)) {
         AltaLote ventana=new AltaLote();
         ControllerLote controlador=new ControllerLote(ventana);
         ventana.addController(controlador);
         ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
} 
}
```

The main window code:

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import Controller.GUI.Controller;

public class MenuPrincipal extends JMenu{

private JFrame frame;
public JMenuItem miALote;
Controller controlador;
private JTable table;

public void addController (Controller mc){
    controlador=mc;
}
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MenuPrincipal() {
    initialize();
}
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
public void initialize() {
    JMenuItem miALote = new JMenuItem("Dar de alta nuevo lote...");
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu mnLote = new JMenu("Lote");
    menuBar.add(mnLote);
    mnLote.add(miALote);
    miALote.addActionListener(controlador);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 390, 139);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    frame.setSize(416, 274);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public JMenuItem getAgregarLote() {
    return miALote;
}

public void setAgregarLote(JMenuItem miALote) {
    this.miALote = miALote;
}

}
```

Comment: When calling `initialize`, its likely that `controlador` is `null`...

Comment: Why does `MenuPrincipal` need to extend `JMenu`?  And why does it then create a brand new `JFrame` within it's `initialize` method?  I think you have bigger problems then just your action listener...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code...

- When constructor an instance of `MenuPrincipal`, you call `initialize` and attempt to register `controlador` as the `ActionListener` for `miALote`, but `controlador` is `null`...
- When calling `addController` the method does nothing (to register itself as the `ActionListener`)
- In `MenuPrincipal`, `miALote` is declared as a instance field (`public JMenuItem miALote;`), but you declare it as a local variable within in the `intitalize` methd (`JMenuItem miALote = new JMenuItem("Dar de alta nuevo lote...");` meaning that the instance field is `null`, so when you do `if (e.getSource().equals(ventanaControlada.miALote)) {`, the result will always be `false`...
- Why does `MenuPrincipal` need to extend from `JMenu` when all it does is create a new `JFrame`?
- `public void setAgregarLote(JMenuItem miALote) {` makes no sense as you're not rebuilding the menu in response to the call...
- Your concept of MVC seems very skewed to me.  You should avoid exposing your UI elements to the controller, as it should not care, it only wants to know when something happens (based on an agreed contract) and respond to the event
- Frankly, I have no idea of how to help you without you first providing a runnable example of your code...